# SQL Server 2000 - Default Value for varchar fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a sql server nvarchar field with a "Default Value or Binding" of empty string.  It also happens to be a not null field.

Does this mean that there is no default or that it is a default of a string with no characters in it.

If I don't insert a value, will it insert with an empty string or fail with a "not null" error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default is a blank (empty) string.

If you don't provide a value, the insert will be successful and the value will be blank, not null.

Answer (score 3):

Its the same as (assuming data is the col in question):

```
create table #t (id int, data varchar(100) not null default(''))
```

So:

```
insert into #t (id) values (1) 
insert into #t (id,data) values (2,default) 
insert into #t (id,data) values (3, 'allowed') 

select * from #t
```

will return

```
1
2
3 allowed
```

and ..

```
insert into #t (id,data) values (1, null) 
-- will error
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a true empty string as a default, then it will autopopulate with a 0 length string.

You should be careful to ensure it is a 0 length string and not nothing though.  If for instance you are looking in the table builder gui for SSMS and it shows a blank for "Default Value or Binding", that means that there is no default value and an insert will fail if it is not populated.  If you want it to have a 0 length string, populate it with '' (two single-quotes together with nothing in between.)

Answer (score 0):

Default value for a column is just that - sql server will put that value when you dont supply one for the column. The value in the column will be an empty string. Not null error will not happen